# How does React split DOM updates and browser paints?

Tags: reactjs

This is the sequence of tasks as I understand:

1. render,
2. reconcile,
3. update DOM,
4. call layout effects
5. browser paint
6. call effects

When I make a change to the DOM like titleRef.current.innerText = 'Hello', the change seems to instantaneous on the browser. There seems to be no difference between a DOM update and a browser paint.

So, how does React split a DOM update from a browser paint? Looked at the source code but could not understand much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the lifecycle of a react component:

1. Run lazy initializers
2. Run rest of the code other than hooks.
3. Create or update virtual dom (here the virtual dom is updated)
4. cleanup of useLayouteffect (unmount stage)
5. useLayoutEffect().
6. Browser paints the screen (real dom is updated)
7. cleanup of useEffect (unmount stage)
8. useEffect().

For more details: https://www.bepo.dev/react-function-component-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Every update to the DOM makes a paint at the browser.

This is why Reacts' virtual DOM makes it more efficient. It batches all those changes into one "package" and then sends it to the DOM to handle the change on the screen (paint).

The call effects (I assume you mean the useEffect hook) is just another "package" to the DOM to make another painting after the virtual DOM is done with its "package" and the real DOM has finished with its painting.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This diagram helps well to understand the whole process